# Download image with Express and show in Vue with AJAX

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, asynchronous

I encountered an issue, that maybe some of you have answer for. I have a dashboard-like app running on MEVN Stack. I want the user to be able to upload his image and store it in backend server, because as I understood, it is not possible to upload to VueJS project public folder directly.

So I found a way to upload it thanks to some post I found here. But I cannot find a way back. My image is store on my backend server and I want to get it using axios in blob form and display it in VueJS. It should be pretty simple but there something I may missed.

First I get the name of my image file and send it like this with Express:
`res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname,"../../images/societies/",result.img_link));`

I also return a default image url if there is no image, which works fine, but not the fetched images. The problem is I cannot access the image directly using URL, it is not accessible. So I have to find a way to get it as a blob I guess and display it.

Here is the code I use to get my Image in frontend, VueJS (script part):

```
getSocietyImage(society) {
    if(society.image){
      this.$http
        .get(this.apiUrl + "society/getImg/" + society.id)
        .then(image => {
          return image.data
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    }else{
        return this.basicImgUrl
    }
}
```

Here is the code in the template part which is a part of a v-for directive:

```
<img
    :src="getSocietyImage(society)"
    alt="content-img"
    class="responsive card-img-top"
/>
```

Below is what I get from the request from a console.log():
[image: request_result]

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: How did you determine about "I cannot access the image directly using URL, it is not accessible"? If you still wish to show image from binary that you already have locally you should convert it to base64 string and the result string should be a data URL like this: `data:image/png;base64,<image_in_base64_here>`

Comment: About data URLs see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problem 1:  Template methods

You shouldn't bind to methods.  The method will run every time the template is re-rendered, which means whenever some relevant data changes.

#### Problem 2: Template async

Template rendering is synchronous, which means you can't bind to an async method at all.  You should use a lifecycle hook (this example uses a URL):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      myimage: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getImage() {
      // Just a mockup of returning something async
      return await 'https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.svg';
    }   
  },
  async created() {
    this.myimage = await this.getImage();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <img :src="myimage">
</div>
```

#### Problem 3: Binary data in HTML

You can either send back the raw binary or convert to base 64

#### 3a. Raw binary (Use a `blob`)

**Server**

```js
res.sendFile(file);  // Send raw binary
```

**Browser**

```html
<img :src="myimage" />
```

```js
async created() {
  const { data } = await this.getImage(); // Binary from server
  const blob = new Blob([data]);
  this.myimage = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}
```

<sup>*Note: Don't forget to clean up with [`URL.revokeObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL)*</sup>

#### 3b. Base64

Or you could convert the binary to Base64 with Express first (but Base64 takes up about ~33% more bandwidth than binary):

**Server**

```js
const bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
const base64 = new Buffer.from(bitmap).toString("base64");
res.send(base64);  // Send base64 instead of the raw file binary
```

**Browser**

```html
<img :src="myimage" />
```

```js
async created() {
  const { data } = await this.getImage(); // base64 data from server
  this.myimage = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I was off this weekend! I tried it, it works great really! Thank you a lot, it was also informative about Vue! I guess, if my file is not a png, but jpg it could work the same way just changing the prefix?

Comment: Hi, I'm glad it helped.  It will work as-is with a jpg too.  Also, you actually don't have to convert to Base64, I added the info for raw binary too, which is probably preferable.

Comment: Thank you for such a great and detailed explanation. 
Quick note: new Buffer throws error in ts and new should be omitted.
In addition, is there a performance difference between the last two methods (Buffer and Blob)?

Comment: @fafa.mnzm - I haven't tested performance, but here are some considerations:  https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to/

Comment: I read 200 SO threads on this topic, and this was the only one I could get to work. I used the base64 method. Thank you!